# compare two strings of same content

Tags: php

i want to compare two strings if there is the same content (text).

I have these two strings

String1 - $preset->message

```
Dear {contact_firstname} {contact_lastname}

Thank you for registering on the {companyname} CRM System.

We just wanted to say welcome.

Please contact us if you need any help.

Click here to view your profile: {crm_url}

Kind Regards,
{email_signature}

(This is an automated email, so please don't reply to this email address)
```

String2 - $_data['message']

```
Dear {contact_firstname} {contact_lastname}

Thank you for registering on the {companyname} CRM System.

We just wanted to say welcome.

Please contact us if you need any help.

Click here to view your profile: {crm_url}

Kind Regards, {email_signature}

(This is an automated email, so please don't reply to this email address)
```

so i trie to compare them in this ways

first

```
if ($_data['message']!=$preset->message){...}
```

for me bothe strings are the same but the code above said its different

so i trie to get more infos

```
$sim = similar_text($_data['message'], $preset->message, $perc);
echo "similarity: $sim ($perc %) - ";
```

As Result i get 99.428571428571 %

So How i can chek in a easy and working way if the text is already the same or not? My tries seems not the right way for do that...

Thanks in advance for helping me at this.

Comment: After the `Kind Regards`, one has a CR, the other not, at least from what I see in the description right now.

Comment: You used `!=` instead `==` in compare

Comment: Please [edit] your question so it contains a [mcve]. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to trim the white spaces, tabs and line breaks to compare this kind of lengthy strings. Try the below code.

```
$str1 = preg_replace("/\s+/", " ", $str1);
$str2 = preg_replace("/\s+/", " ", $str2);

if($str1 == $str2) {
    echo '1';
} else {
    echo '0';
}
```

Comment: Using your code `Hello\sWorld` and `Hello\s\s\sWorld` considered as same text

Comment: This conveniently fixes exactly one problem, and does nothing to address, for example, an extra space in the text that would cause them to appear equal despite not being so.

Comment: Yes to both. String looks like mail template and OP's checking while creating a template not while sending a mail. So, I think it's fine with comparing the strings without any white spaces.

Comment: seems that this will work, mybe there is something else what i have to think for?

Answer (score 0):

```
$str1 = "Dear {contact_firstname} {contact_lastname}

Thank you for registering on the {companyname} CRM System.

We just wanted to say welcome.

Please contact us if you need any help.

Click here to view your profile: {crm_url}

Kind Regards,
{email_signature}

(This is an automated email, so please don't reply to this email address)";


$str2 = "Dear {contact_firstname} {contact_lastname}

Thank you for registering on the {companyname} CRM System.

We just wanted to say welcome.

Please contact us if you need any help.

Click here to view your profile: {crm_url}

Kind Regards, {email_signature}

(This is an automated email, so please don't reply to this email address)";



echo strcmp($str1, $str2) ? "Equal" : "Not Equal";
```

Comment: Note: `strcmp` is case sensitive

Comment: @TamilvananN if he needs to ignore case then strcasecmp should work.

Comment: If i try "strcmp($_data['message'],$preset->message)" it will return 7168 - so its not equal for this function...!?

Comment: @Rene that's mean while comparing your  $_data['message'] has 7168 character more than $preset->message.

Comment: @Rene could you dump $_data['message'] and $preset->message just before compare to check if value has not changed anyway ?